# How to get the rows that have min timestamp using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlite

Would anybody help me with this problem? 
(Please see attached image below)

`Sample Table`

[image]

`what should be the result`

[image]

Comment: you want min timestamp of each id? is your timestamp in datetime format?

Comment: Hello @Arvaan yes, and it's corresponding Value. You can see sample pictures on the link provided.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [ask].

Comment: option one: actually read some SQL documentation and come up with your own (not yet quite working) approach. Then we'll take a look at it - option two: wait and see if people at [sql server](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/117360) are happy to help

Comment: `top-N-per-group` http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86415/retrieving-n-rows-per-group

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a case for [RANK()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx)

See this example:

```
SELECT EmployeeCode
    , Timestamp
    , Value
FROM (
    SELECT RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeCode ORDER BY Timestamp) AS RN
        , EmployeeCode
        , Timestamp
        , Value
    FROM dbo.SampleTable
    ) AS ST
WHERE ST.RN = 1;
```

It will generate a number (1, 2, 3, 4, ... n) for each row.

Please note that I'm doing a `PARTITION BY`, which resets number for each different EmployeeCode. So this query pretty much generates unique number for each employee and it depends on timestamp value. Lowest timestamp value will have it as 1.

**Official documentation says**

> If two or more rows tie for a rank, each tied rows receives the same
>   rank. For example, if the two top salespeople have the same SalesYTD
>   value, they are both ranked one. The salesperson with the next highest
>   SalesYTD is ranked number three, because there are two rows that are
>   ranked higher. Therefore, the RANK function does not always return
>   consecutive integers.

Since you provided a screenshot only, I've added a quick numbers next to rows. So you can imagine how it's looking.

[image]

Comment: Hello @Evaldas Buinauskas, thanks for detailed explaination, noted that. :) regarding on your code provided, I have some issues. Result are quite wrong.

Comment: What's not right? It'd be a better idea to post a query to generate some data, instead of screenshoting. It would help building query. :)

Comment: Hello @Evaldas Buinauskas, I would like to post my code, but I think, my problem would be more understandable if I will post a screenshot of what I need to be the output.

Comment: You just need to post some sample data as a text and expected output.

Comment: Hello this is the sample data result when I use your provided code. please click the link. :)
http://imgur.com/pPh48B6

Comment: and for what I expected result.
kindly check this link.
http://i.stack.imgur.com/qQX3g.jpg
thanks :)

Comment: Could you please post it as a **text** (even better as a query or even fiddle) and post expected output with it? In your question.

Comment: Hello @Evaldas Buinauskas thanks a lot for the help. the code is good, as well as the result. I just forgot to change your edited code from **ROW_NUMBER()** to **RANK()** . Highly appriciated your quick response. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select min(timestamp), employeeCode from table_name where employeeCode in (select employeeCode from table_name group by employeeCode)
```

Comment: Hello @Arvaan, I used your code provided above, unfortunately, the column Value (just like from the sample picture) are missing.

Comment: oops. I thought it was your input table

Comment: Hello @Arvaan, no the column Value was included on the table.

Answer (score 0):

I think a basic group by will do the trick:

```
SELECT employeeCode, value, min(timestamp)
FROM table
GROUP BY employeeCode, value
```

Comment: Hello @Zohar, I tried your code but it shows all the items from column Value and its Timestamp and EmployeeCode. what I need is just the min(Timestamp) and its EmployeeCode and its Value. (just like what is shown on the picture I provided above)

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use Row_number() also to generate minimum result : 

SELECT EMPLOYEECODE,
       TIMESTAMP,
       VALUE
FROM  (SELECT Row_number()
                OVER (
                  PARTITION BY EMPLOYEECODE
                  ORDER BY TIMESTAMP)RN,
              EMPLOYEECODE,
              TIMESTAMP,
              VALUE
       FROM   TABLE)A
WHERE  RN = 1
```